# why am i getting the below exception

Tags: java

My service class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity

    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/confirm").permitAll();

        }


    }
```

My pojo:

```
        @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")

        public class User {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
            @Column(name = "id")
            private int id;

            @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
            @Email(message = "Please provide a valid e-mail")
            @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide an e-mail")
            private String email;

            @Column(name = "password")
            @Transient
            private String password;

            @Column(name = "first_name")
            @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide your first name")
            private String firstName;

            @Column(name = "last_name")
            @NotEmpty(message = "Please provide your last name")
            private String lastName;

            @Column(name = "enabled")
            private boolean enabled;

            @Column(name = "confirmation_token")
            private String confirmationToken;


            public String getConfirmationToken() {
                return confirmationToken;
            }

            public void setConfirmationToken(String confirmationToken) {
                this.confirmationToken = confirmationToken;
            }


            public int getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(int id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getPassword() {
                return password;
            }

            public void setPassword(String password) {
                this.password = password;
            }

            public String getFirstName() {
                return firstName;
            }

            public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
                this.firstName = firstName;
            }

            public String getLastName() {
                return lastName;
            }

            public void setLastName(String lastName) {
                this.lastName = lastName;
            }

            public String getEmail() {
                return email;
            }

            public void setEmail(String email) {
                this.email = email;
            }

            public boolean getEnabled() {
                return enabled;
            }

            public void setEnabled(boolean value) {
                this.enabled = value;
            }
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
 public class RegisterController {

        private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        private UserService userService;
        private EmailService emailService;

        @Autowired
        public RegisterController(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,
                UserService userService, EmailService emailService) {
            this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
            this.userService = userService;
            this.emailService = emailService;
        }

        // Return registration form template
        @RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView showRegistrationPage(ModelAndView modelAndView, User user){
            modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
            modelAndView.setViewName("register");
            return modelAndView;
        }

        // Process form input data
        @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView processRegistrationForm(ModelAndView modelAndView, @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) {

            // Lookup user in database by e-mail
            User userExists = userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail());

            System.out.println(userExists);

            if (userExists != null) {
                modelAndView.addObject("alreadyRegisteredMessage", "Oops!  There is already a user registered with the email provided.");
                modelAndView.setViewName("register");
                bindingResult.reject("email");
            }

            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) { 
                modelAndView.setViewName("register");       
            } else { // new user so we create user and send confirmation e-mail

                // Disable user until they click on confirmation link in email
                user.setEnabled(false);

                // Generate random 36-character string token for confirmation link
                user.setConfirmationToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

                userService.saveUser(user);

                String appUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName();

                SimpleMailMessage registrationEmail = new SimpleMailMessage();
                registrationEmail.setTo(user.getEmail());
                registrationEmail.setSubject("Registration Confirmation");
                registrationEmail.setText("To confirm your e-mail address, please click the link below:\n"
                        + appUrl + "/confirm?token=" + user.getConfirmationToken());
                registrationEmail.setFrom("noreply@domain.com");

                emailService.sendEmail(registrationEmail);

                modelAndView.addObject("confirmationMessage", "A confirmation e-mail has been sent to " + user.getEmail());
                modelAndView.setViewName("register");
            }

            return modelAndView;
        }

        // Process confirmation link
        @RequestMapping(value="/confirm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView confirmRegistration(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam("token") String token) {

            User user = userService.findByConfirmationToken(token);

            if (user == null) { // No token found in DB
                modelAndView.addObject("invalidToken", "Oops!  This is an invalid confirmation link.");
            } else { // Token found
                modelAndView.addObject("confirmationToken", user.getConfirmationToken());
            }

            modelAndView.setViewName("confirm");
            return modelAndView;        
        }

        // Process confirmation link
        @RequestMapping(value="/confirm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView confirmRegistration(ModelAndView modelAndView, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams, RedirectAttributes redir) {

            modelAndView.setViewName("confirm");

            Zxcvbn passwordCheck = new Zxcvbn();

            Strength strength = passwordCheck.measure(requestParams.get("password"));

            if (strength.getScore() < 3) {
                //modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", "Your password is too weak.  Choose a stronger one.");
                bindingResult.reject("password");

                redir.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "Your password is too weak.  Choose a stronger one.");

                modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:confirm?token=" + requestParams.get("token"));
                System.out.println(requestParams.get("token"));
                return modelAndView;
            }

            // Find the user associated with the reset token
            User user = userService.findByConfirmationToken(requestParams.get("token"));

            // Set new password
            user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(requestParams.get("password")));

            // Set user to enabled
            user.setEnabled(true);

            // Save user
            userService.saveUser(user);

            modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "Your password has been set!");
            return modelAndView;        
        }
```

Below is the error I am getting even if I even downgraded MySql back to 5.7:

> > org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

My application.properties:

```
# ===============================
# TOMCAT
# ===============================
server.address=127.0.0.1
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true

# ===============================
# SMTP EMAIL
# ===============================
spring.mail.host = smtp.mailhost.com
spring.mail.username = mailUser
spring.mail.password = mailPass
spring.mail.port = 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true

# ===============================
# = LOGGING
# ===============================
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR

# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/point?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Africa/pretoria
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=langton
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=10000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
# ===============================
# = Thymeleaf configurations
# ===============================
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Comment: Are you sure your DB data is correct? First wild guess, is the port really 3308 not 3306 (default)? Is your DB server running?

Comment: i did set my db to 3308

Comment: Once I struggled to connect to the MySQL DB because I forgot to use `useSSL=false` in my db connectionString, like `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/point?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Africa/pretoria` you can give it a shot but 0 guarantees

Comment: yes i did try to change but same error

Comment: I have a feeling that something is incorrect in the properties data or db itself, not in the code. 
Could you please change to your `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`      to      `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` ? `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` is something I could NOT find here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: did it help? Any other exception?

Comment: it keeps giving same exception

Comment: What happens when you use something like the "telnet" command to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 3308?   Are your Tomcat and MySQL on the same machine?  (That's a "stupid question" ... except if it isn't!)

Comment: Have you tried it mysql://localhost:3308/point without parameters ?

Comment: its wierd because when i run the application it says give this exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'point'... but it still continues to launch the application at tomcate 8080  but i have a database ith the name point